# Stop page reload while Posting data

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, submit, reload

I have to post data to php but when I do, the page reloads. I have tried fixing this using answers given in similar questions but none of them yield proper results. Thanks for your help.

```
<!--HTML-->
<form method="post" action="index.php" onclick = "sendForm(event);">            
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="rand5_code">
    <input type="submit" href=""  name="rand5_btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter">
</form>

 //Javascript
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            function sendForm(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        </script>
```

Another way that I was recommended was by using ajax:

```
<form id="form" >
    <input  style="width:200;margin-top:5px" type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="installer2_code" placeholder="Enter Code">
     <input type="submit" href="#" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" class="btn btn-success" id="form" onclick =" sendForm(event);" value="Enter">
   </form>

<script>
    $('#form').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
           var name = $(#code).val(),
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'header_php.php',
        });
    });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `onclick = "sendForm(event);"` in button instead of form

Comment: The data does not pass when I do this. Thanks!

Comment: Ok then use onsubmit = "sendForm(event);" in form.

Comment: That is not passing data either.

Comment: Then you should use ajax to submit form.

Answer (score 0):

you could change [`onsubmit`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZhaar-pPUAhXJpo8KHVMlDCsQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_form_submit.asp&usg=AFQjCNHUCCmJotBf1Vfe61sQrz-L_5fpPA&sig2=_hxYwLGVGYqWDZpyiUk7tA) instead of `onclick` in the form

```js
function sendForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="sendForm(event);"><!--changes-->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="rand5_code">
  <input type="submit" href="" name="rand5_btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the button does not work when I do this. It didn't work on my original code either, therefore I believe there may be a problem elsewhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change button `type="submit"` to button `Type="button"` and
Use jquery ajax

```
$("#btnid").click(function(){
    $.ajax({

    method: "POST",

    url: "some.php",

    data: { name: $('#code').val()}

    })

    .done(function( msg ) {

    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );

    });
})
```

Also remove `action` from form

Comment: Does this change how I get the POST data in php ($_post[installer_code1]) because the data is still not getting across?

Comment: Yes, make another file some.php for php code. You can get data on that file with $_POST

Comment: This did not work either. More specifically, the button is stuck and stops functioning.

Comment: Have you added jQuery library?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I had this link <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok, then there would be some other problem. Have you added id in button?

Comment: The console log does not show any errors. I added id="form" to button. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Even though I couldn't locate an error, an error noise is played when the button is pressed.

Comment: This is  ajax documentation .  You can check here
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: I edited my post to add the method you recommended by using Ajax. Unfortunately, this method does not work. Is there a possibility that some outside factor is impacting the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add `onsubmit="return false;"` to your form. In you js function `e` is clickEvent not is SubmitEvent, submitEvent make page reload.

```
<!--HTML-->
    <form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="return false;" onclick = "sendForm(event);">            
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="rand5_code">
        <input type="submit" href=""  name="rand5_btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter">
    </form>

     //Javascript
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function sendForm(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: The data from 'code' does not pass to php and the button does not perform the php ( if(isset($_POST['rand5_btn'])) code I have under the php section. Thanks!

Comment: If you want post data to php server without reload page then  only one way to do this - Make a ajax request. You can use jQuery lib, folow link https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: You can put your form to a Iframe and keep origin html code, when click is trigged only Iframe be reload